# Filter and transform json with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, transform

Using JavaScript, I need all the elements inside `groups.1` to have the following value value **:**

```
{"schemas": "block"}
```

Also, I need that the elements inside `groups.101` to have the following value **:**

```
{"schemas": "all",
"native": "write"}
```

The original JSON looks like this **:**

```
 {
  "revision": 76,
  "groups": {
    "1": {
      "26": {
        "schemas": "block"
      },
      "138": {
        "schemas": "block"
      },
      "179": {
        "schemas": "block"
      },
      "245": {
        "schemas": "all",
        "native": "write"
      }
    },
    "101": {
      "167": {
        "schemas": "block"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The expected result looks like this

```
{
  "revision": 76,
  "groups": {
    "1": {
      "26": {
        "schemas": "block"
      },
      "138": {
        "schemas": "block"
      },
      "179": {
        "schemas": "block"
      },
      "245": {
        "schemas": "block"
      }
    },
    "101": {
      "167": {
       "schemas": "all",
       "native": "write"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json))

Object.keys(res.groups.1).forEach(key => res.groups.1[key] = {"schemas": "block"}
Object.keys(res.groups.101).forEach(key => res.groups.101[key] = {"schemas": "all",
"native": "write"}
```

is a direct solution, because you are starting from a json object so the JSON serialization copy should succeed.

we can generalize by splitting a path into an array and applying that in a "filter" step, then applying a function.

```
const filterTransformFactory = (filter, transform) => json => {
  head = json
  while(filter.length) {
    head = head[filter.shift()]
  }
  Object.keys(head).forEach(key => transform(head, key))
}

const oneFilter = filterTransformFactory(['groups', 1], (o, key) => o[key] = {"schemas": "block"})
const oneooneFilter = filterTransformFactory(['groups', 101], (o, key) => o[key] = {"schemas": "all",
    "native": "write"})
```

and apply that to a copy of the json. a bit further refactoring can make this rather pretty, by providing a replaceTransform function:

```
const filterTransformFactory = (filter, transform) => json => {
  head = json
  while(filter.length) {
    head = head[filter.shift()]
  }
  Object.keys(head).forEach(key => transform(head, key))
}
const replaceTransformFactory = payload => (o, key) => o[key] = payload

const oneTransform = replaceTransformFactory({"schemas": "block"})
const oneFilterTransform = filterTransformFactory(['groups', 1], oneTransform)

const oneooneTransform = replaceTransformFactory({"schemas": "all", "native": "write"})
const oneooneFilterTransform = filterTransformFactory(['groups', 101], oneooneTransform)

const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json))
oneFilterTransform(result)
oneooneFilterTransform(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a config object with all the groups we want to transform and their respective values. Then just iterated over the groups and replaced the values.

```js
const transform = (json, config) => {
  Object.keys(json.groups).forEach(group => {
    // Skip groups that are not in config
    if (!(group in config)) return;

    const keys = Object.keys(json.groups[group]);
    for (const key of keys) {
      json.groups[group][key] = { ...config[group] };
    }
  });
};

// All the the groups we want to transform
const config = {
  "1": {
    "schemas": "block"
  },
  "101": {
    "schemas": "all",
    "native": "write"
  }
};

const json = {
  "revision": 76,
  "groups": {
    "1": {
      "26": {
        "schemas": "block"
      },
      "138": {
        "schemas": "block"
      },
      "179": {
        "schemas": "block"
      },
      "245": {
        "schemas": "all",
        "native": "write"
      }
    },
    "101": {
      "167": {
        "schemas": "block"
      }
    }
  }
};

transform(json, config);
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's a straight forward requirement that `groups.1` objects should contain `"schemas": "block"` and `groups.101` objects should contain `"schemas": "all", "native": "write"`. Hence, we can try this way **:**

```js
const jsonObj = {
    "revision": 76,
    "groups": {
        "1": {
            "26": {
                "schemas": "block"
            },
            "138": {
                "schemas": "block"
            },
            "179": {
                "schemas": "block"
            },
            "245": {
                "schemas": "all",
                "native": "write"
            }
        },
        "101": {
            "167": {
                "schemas": "block"
            }
        }
    }
};

function transformObj(group1, group101) {
  Object.keys(group1).forEach(key => {
    group1[key] = {
      "schemas": "block"
    }
  });
  Object.keys(group101).forEach(key => {
    group101[key] = {
      "schemas": "all",
      "native": "write"
    }
  });
}

transformObj(jsonObj['groups']['1'], jsonObj['groups']['101']);

console.log(jsonObj);
```